# PERL: How to avoid WHILE for Socket?

Tags: perl, sockets

I'd like to write client-server high-loaded tool based on Sockets. 
I have common code:

```
  $buffsize = 1024;
  my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET(
    PeerAddr => $host,
    PeerPort => $port,
    Proto => 'tcp',
    Timeout => 5,
   );  

  connect($sock, $paddr);
  my $a = send($sock, $data, $buffsize);

    my $in;
      $content = "";
      while (1){        
        my $count = sysread($sock, $in, $buffsize);
        $content .= $in;
        }
      }
  close($sock);
```

But when I fork() this code 1000 times it loads CPU 100%. How can I avoid WHILE() to optimize source code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at event oriented (e.g. non-blocking) programming like with [`AnyEvent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent), [`POE`](https://metacpan.org/pod/POE), [`IO::Async`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO%3a%3aAsync) or similar.